# mysql update table column with multiple values from same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a mysql table with columns: customer, dateOrder.
One customer can have orders in multiple dates. I want to add a new column with the farthest date order for each customer. So far i tried this:

```
UPDATE mytable  
   SET MINDATE = (SELECT min(DATEORDER) 
                    FROM (SELECT * 
                            FROM mytable 
                           GROUP 
                              BY CUSTOMER
                          ) tblTmp
                 )
```

, where tblTmp is a temporary table;The problem is that it brings the same date for all my customers (the farthest date in the table). Any ideas?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. - A tip is to start with a SELECT that returns the desired result, and then build up to the UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` to match the original table with the subquery:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT customer, MIN(dateorder) AS mindate
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY customer) AS t2 ON t1.customer = t2.customer
SET t1.mindate = t2.mindate
```

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm! I'm quite new with databases and I was avoiding the Join :)

Comment: Embrace the JOIN! it is the fundamental operation in relational databases.